# React 16.4 setState calls componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to migrate my react 15.6 project to 16.4, but I noticed very weird behaviour with `setState` method. Check this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class TestCompo extends Component {

  static propTypes = {};

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.onClick = ::this.onClick;
  }

  state = {
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps, nextContext) {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
  }

  onClick () {
    this.setState(() => ({
      clickCount: this.state.clickCount + 1
    }));
  }

  render () {
    return (
     <div>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.onClick}>Test buttons</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On React 15.6 everything works fine, but on React 16.4 pressing button calls also `componentWillReceiveProps` - despite that none of props were updated. Does anybody know reason for that?

Comment: this.state.clickCount + 1 => You shouldnt be mutating the state. You can copy the value to a new variable and then call stateState() right ?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible demo, I created a sandbox and it does work as expected, https://codesandbox.io/s/74jxjjpl8j . Also since you are using functional setState, you might as well use it correctly, `this.setState((prevState) => ({
      clickCount: prevState.clickCount + 1
    }));`

Comment: OK, it turns out that this is a problem with react-css-modules used in parent component - for react 16.3 and higher they have such bug.